# Problem with Date Query - sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have this date's & Time's:

date1: 10/04/2010 - Time: 08:09

date2: 11/04/2010 - Time: 08:14

i need to show all the date's between 10/04/2010 time 06:00 and 11/04/2010 time 6:00

i write this: `select * from MyTbl where ((Tdate BETWEEN '20100410' AND '20100411')  and (Ttime BETWEEN '06:00' and '06:00'))`

but i get empty table

thank's in advance

Comment: what data type is Tdate and Ttime?

Comment: Tdate and Ttime are datetime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both columns are datetime, simply add them so you can do a "proper" range query

```
where Tdate +Ttime BETWEEN '2010-04-10 06:00:00' AND '2010-04-11 06:00:00'
```

Comment: +1 for Tdate +Ttime and then using the "BETWEEN". Saves atleast 2 more lines. :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct.

What your resultset returns is all the records that are valid between 10/04/2010 06:00 - 10/04/2010 06:00 or 11/04/2010 06:00 - 11/04/2010 06:00.

(Which means there are exactly 2 valid minutes for records to be retrieved).

You need to filter according to the full date including time.

Answer (score 1):

Find total number of orders that were placed in each month of the year 1987.

```
SELECT COUNT(OrdId) AS TotalNumberOfOrder FROM OrderABC WHERE OrdDate > '1987-01-01' AND OrdDate < '1987-12-31';
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(OrdId) AS TotalNumberOfOrder FROM OrderABC WHERE OrdDate BETWEEN '1987-01-01' AND '1987-12-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select * 
from MyTbl 
where (Tdate = '20100410' AND Time >= '06:00') 
   OR (TDATE > '20100410' AND TDATE < '20100410')
   OR (Tdate = '20100411' AND Time <= '06:00')
```

Comment: do you think that will really work? You can use 'AND' instead.

Comment: select *  
from MyTbl  
where (Tdate = '20100410' AND Time >= '06:00')  
   AND (Tdate > '20100410' AND TDATE < '20100410') 
   AND (Tdate = '20100411' AND Time <= '06:00')